# Finding vector associated with a form of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces, riesz-representation-theorem

I need to solve an exercise that asks for the vector associated to a certain form of the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. I am pretty sure this "associated vector" is related to Riesz's representation theorem, but I am not sure how to proceed. The form is given by:

$$F(f) = \int_0^1 f(x^2) x dx$$

While it is easy to check that it is linear:

$$F(\lambda f + \mu g) = \int_0^1 (\lambda f + \mu g)(x^2) x dx = \lambda \int_0^1 f(x^2) x dx + \mu \int_0^1 g(x^2) x dx = \lambda F(f) + \mu F(g)$$

I don't think it is continuous, because I can't find a $g\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ so that $F(f) = \langle f | g \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)g(x)dx$. I may be confused, but I think that since we are in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, we should use the usual inner product and I don't see a way to equate that with the definition of $F$, which has an x^2 as the argumento of the function in the integrand. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Try to do a substitution first ($y = x^2$).

Comment: If I do that, then the limits of integration both are y = $\infty$, and then I can't identify the integral that I get with the norm of two functions.

Comment: How do you get $\infty$ for $y =x^2$ if $x\in [0,1]$?

Comment: Sorry, I was being stupid. You're right. I thought the integration limits where $-\infty$ and $\infty$ because I had just solved a bunch of exercises where that was the case. Thank you!